# Difference between cursors opened within a session vs out a session

Tags: mongodb

I refer to quite a lot of documentation for the server session concept, but I just can't understand what it is. What does this sentence mean?

> By default, cursors not opened within a session automatically timeout
> after 10 minutes of inactivity. Cursors opened under a session close
> with the end or timeout of the session.

[Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor:%7E:text=mongoimport.-,cursor,-A%20pointer%20to)

What is a server session?
What is the difference between cursors not opened within a session vs cursors opened under a session?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Mongo.startSession/#mongodb-method-Mongo.startSession